# Scala for comprehension of sequence inside a Try

Tags: scala, exception, for-comprehension

I am writing a Scala program in which there is an operation that creates a sequence. The operation might fail, so I enclose it inside a `Try`. I want to do sequence creation and enumeration inside a for comprehension, so that a successfully-created sequence yields a sequence of tuples where the first element is the sequence and the second is an element of it.

To simplify the problem, make my sequence a `Range` of integers and define a `createRange` function that fails if it is asked to create a range of an odd length. Here is a simple for comprehension that does what I want.

```
import scala.util.Try

def createRange(n: Int): Try[Range] = {
  Try {
    if (n % 2 == 1) throw new Exception
    else Range(0, n)
  }
}

def rangeElements(n: Int) {
  for {
    r <- createRange(n)
    x <- r
  } println(s"$r\t$x")
}

def main(args: Array[String]) {
  println("Range length 3")
  rangeElements(3)

  println("Range length 4")
  rangeElements(4)
}
```

If you run this it correctly prints.

```
Range length 3
Range length 4
Range(0, 1, 2, 3)   0
Range(0, 1, 2, 3)   1
Range(0, 1, 2, 3)   2
Range(0, 1, 2, 3)   3
```

Now I would like to rewrite my `rangeElements` function so that instead of printing as a side-effect it returns a sequence of integers, where the sequence is empty if the range was not created. What I want to write is this.

```
def rangeElements(n: Int):Seq[(Range,Int)] = {
  for {
    r <- createRange(n)
    x <- r
  } yield (r, x)
}
// rangeElements(3) returns an empty sequence
// rangeElements(4) returns the sequence (Range(0,1,2,3), 0), (Range(0,1,2,3), 1) etc.
```

This gives me two type mismatch compiler errors. The `r <- createRange(n)` line required `Seq[Int]` but found `scala.util.Try[Nothing]`. The `x <- r` line required `scala.util.Try[?]` but found `scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int]`.

Presumably there is some type erasure with the `Try` that is messing me up, but I can't figure out what it is. I've tried various `toOption` and `toSeq` qualifiers on the lines in the for comprehension to no avail.

If I only needed to yield the range elements I could explicitly handle the `Success` and `Failure` conditions of `createRange` myself as suggested by the first two answers below. However, I need access to both the range and its individual elements.

I realize this is a strange-sounding example. The real problem I am trying to solve is a complicated recursive search, but I don't want to add in all its details because that would just confuse the issue here.

How do I write `rangeElements` to yield the desired sequences?

Answer (score 3):

The problem becomes clear if you translate the for comprehension to its map/flatMap implementation (as described in the [Scala Language Spec 6.19](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/pdfs/ScalaReference.pdf)). The flatMap has the result type `Try[U]` but your function expects `Seq[Int]`.

```
for {
  r <- createRange(n)
  x <- r
} yield x

createRange(n).flatMap {
  case r => r.map {
    case x => x
  }
}
```

Is there any reason why you don't use the `getOrElse` method?

```
def rangeElements(n: Int):Seq[Int] =
  createRange(n) getOrElse Seq.empty
```

Comment: This answer is correct. Unfortunately, it made me realize that my original question which is addresses is too simple. I've amended the question to a more complicated scenario that gets closer to the real problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: Its hard to find the right solution without knowing the actual problem. In the given case you can now use something like `val r = createRange(n) getOrElse Range(0,0); r map { (r, _) }`. I am not sure if you can reach your goal with a for comprehension. You can find the second solution here http://www.scalakata.com/51f05d8ae4b0dcd4a06348da

Answer (score 1):

The `Try` will be `Success` with a `Range` when `n` is even  or a `Failure` with an `Exception` when `n` is odd. In `rangeElements` match and extract those values. `Success` will contain the valid `Range` and `Failure` will contain the `Exception`. Instead of returning the `Exception` return an empty `Seq`.

```
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}

def createRange(n: Int): Try[Range] = {
  Try {
    if (n % 2 == 1) throw new Exception
    else Range(0, n)
  }
}

def rangeElements(n: Int):Seq[Tuple2[Range, Int]] = createRange(n) match {
  case Success(s) => s.map(xs => (s, xs))
  case Failure(f) => Seq()
}    

scala> rangeElements(3)
res35: Seq[(Range, Int)] = List()

scala> rangeElements(4)
res36: Seq[(Range, Int)] = Vector((Range(0, 1, 2, 3),0), (Range(0, 1, 2, 3),1), (Range(0, 1, 2, 3),2), (Range(0, 1, 2,3),3))
```

Comment: This answer is correct. Unfortunately, it made me realize that my original question which is addresses is too simple. I've amended the question to a more complicated scenario that gets closer to the real problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: Changing `case Success(s) => s` to this `case Success(s) => s.map(xs => (s, xs))` gives the output `Seq[(Range, Int)] = Vector((Range(0, 1, 2, 3),0), (Range(0, 1, 2, 3),1), (Range(0, 1, 2, 3),2), (Range(0, 1, 2, 3),3))`.

Comment: I like the pattern matching solution. However, the for comprehension is completely useless. One can just use the match as the functions body...

Comment: Agreed. Started with what @W.P.McNeill posted and worked with that. I've updated the answer.